# save data from api to dataframe

Tags: python, json, api

I have the following output when getting data from an API:

```
{'Textbook': [{'Type': 'Chapters', 'Case': 'Ch09', 'Rates': 
[{'Date': '2021- 04-23T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0}, {'Date': '2021-04-26T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0}, 
{'Date': '2021-04-27T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5}, {'Date': '2021-04-28T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5}, 
{'Date': '2021-04-29T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5}, {'Date': '2021-04-30T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0}]}]}
```

I am trying to get the following output in a dataframe:

```
Date                           Rate
2021- 04-23T00:00:00          10.0
2021-04-26T00:00:00           10.0
2021-04-27T00:00:00           10.5
```

etc

I tried the following code:

```
l=parsed ###this is the output from API 
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in l:
   d1 = {}
   reportDate = []
   price = []
   for j in i['Chapters']:
      reportDate.append(j['Date'])
      price.append(j['Rate'])
   d1['Date'] = reportDate
   d1['Rate'] = price
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(d1))
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

However, I get the following error: `string indices must be integers` for the line `for j in i['Chapters']:`

Comment: Your code resets every time. `price` for example, gets overwritten multiple times before you try assign it to a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below fix on your code will solve your issue. Although the answer by Andreas is a pythonic way!

```
import ast

# Data setup
raw_data="""
{'Textbook': [{'Type': 'Chapters', 'Case': 'Ch09', 'Rates': 
[{'Date': '2021- 04-23T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0}, {'Date': '2021-04-26T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0}, 
{'Date': '2021-04-27T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5}, {'Date': '2021-04-28T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5}, 
{'Date': '2021-04-29T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5}, {'Date': '2021-04-30T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0}]}]}
"""
val=ast.literal_eval(raw_data) # eval to dictionary
```

the fix would be(pls review the comment section)

```
l=val ###this is the output from API, added val in this example 
reportDate = [] # moved out of loop to collect the data
price = [] # moved out of loop to collect the data
#df=pd.DataFrame() build the dataframe once all the data is ready
for i in l: # this is dictionary
    #d1 = {} not needed
    
    for j in l[i][0]['Rates']:
        reportDate.append(j['Date'])
        price.append(j['Rate'])
    #d1['Date'] = reportDate
    #d1['Rate'] = price
#df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(d1))
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':reportDate,"Rate":price})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
d = {'Textbook': [{'Type': 'Chapters', 'Case': 'Ch09', 'Rates':
[{'Date': '2021- 04-23T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0}, {'Date': '2021-04-26T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0},
{'Date': '2021-04-27T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5}, {'Date': '2021-04-28T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5},
{'Date': '2021-04-29T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5}, {'Date': '2021-04-30T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0}]}]}

pd.DataFrame(d.get('Textbook')[0].get('Rates'))

#                    Date  Rate
# 0  2021- 04-23T00:00:00  10.0
# 1   2021-04-26T00:00:00  10.0
# 2   2021-04-27T00:00:00  10.5
# 3   2021-04-28T00:00:00  10.5
# 4   2021-04-29T00:00:00  10.5
# 5   2021-04-30T00:00:00  10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible solutions to your question

You could read a documentation here: https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-save-a-dataframe/

**or** you could try this code

```py
d = {'Textbook': [{'Type': 'Chapters', 'Case': 'Ch09', 'Rates':
[{'Date': '2021- 04-23T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0}, {'Date': '2021-04-26T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0},
{'Date': '2021-04-27T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5}, {'Date': '2021-04-28T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5},
{'Date': '2021-04-29T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.5}, {'Date': '2021-04-30T00:00:00', 'Rate': 10.0}]}]}

pd.DataFrame(d.get('Textbook')[0].get('Rates'))
```

Code doesn't work? Please comment below.. any other questions, I'll be glad to talk.